# Как сохранить последний элемент и доскролить до него?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть пагинация (кнопка показать еще), которая подгружает блоки каждый раз.

Есть вот такой код подзагрузки. Сейчас на данный момент подзагрузка работает, но по клику на кнопку страница скролится в самый вверх, а не к последнему элементу который загружен. Как сохранить последний блок, загрузить контент и проскролить до него. Пример по ссылке: https://tvoidv.ru/culture/

```js
$(document).on('click', '#more-news', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var _url = $(this).attr('data-url');
  send = false; //убираем шумы
  if (_url && !send) {
    $.ajax({
      url: _url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        // включение прелоудера
        send = false;
      },
      complete: function() {
        // отключение прелоудера
      },
      success: function(obj) {
        send = true;

        $(".news-grid-list__mb").last() //Возвращаем последний div-элемент с классом news-grid-list__mb.

        $('#more-news').remove(); //удаляем текущю кнопку
        $("#get_news").append(obj['html']) //добавляе  готвую разметку

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(".news-grid-list__mb").offset().top //Скролл
        }, 1000);

        if ('show_more' == true) {
          $('#more-news').show();
        } else {
          $('#more-news').hide();
        } //добавляем кнопку если пришел флаг
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText + "\r\n" + xhr);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page)

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
```

либо технически вернее

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() });
```

если к конкретному ID, используйте его .scrollTop():

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#myID").scrollTop() }, 1000);
```

Comment: Последний вариант скролится до начала страницы, нужно чтобы скролл был до последнего элемента https://prnt.sc/ubhgug

Comment: если вы правильно указали то должно рабртать. Возьмите проскрольте до футера $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#footerId").scrollTop() }, 1000); и посмотрите что получится